# Java addActionListener error

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener

I was making a button ActionListener in Java, and

```
d1.addActionListener(this);
```

gave me an error on "this", but

```
d1.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
```

works. Why do I need to add the "(ActionListener)"? I've seen in tutorials that the first should work; why not for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply, `this` is not an ActionListener. Does your class implement the ActionListener interface? The compiler is telling you that it doesn't.

i.e., this will work:

```
public class Foo implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //....
    }

}
```

but this won't

```
public class Bar {

}
```

Comment: When I implement ActionListener, it gives me error "The type buttonPrototype must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)" Why is that?

Comment: @Ivy: you class doesn't have the `actionPerformed` method, as I show above. A class that implements an interface must have all the methods  that the interface specifies.

Comment: Hmm, The second syntax doesn't make sense to me either. I would have thought you get a compiler error the second way as well. It actually compiles ok but you get a runtime exception. Learn something every day :) Still wonder why the compiler doesn't catch this as an error?

Answer (score 3):

```
d1.addActionListener(this);
```

This means that the current class shall handle any action event on the `d1` component. And by 'handle' I mean **implement** the **ActionListener** class.

```
public class YourClass implements ActionListener {
    // Member variables
    public YourClass() {
        d1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    // Methods

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Handle event
    }
}
```

You can handle this in another way, by creating an inner separate class:

```
public class YourClass implements ActionListener {
    // Member variables
    public YourClass() {
        d1.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
    }

    // Methods
    class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Handle event
        }
    }
}
```